# paper_trail gem - Can't track destroy event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, paper-trail-gem

I'm using the `paper_trail` gem for a rails project. (ruby 2.3, rails 4.2.5)

`paper_trail` isn't tracking `:destroy` events in my rails app.

Upon investigation the version model with the `destroy` event doesn't seem to be saved because it has a relation to the model which it should track and which is now non-existent (we're recording a destroy event, hence it's intentional that the model is non-existent at this moment).

Here's how I tried to get behind this:

PaperTrail has a model called `Version`. When I set a breakpoint [at the point](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/paper_trail/has_paper_trail.rb#L428) where the `Version` instance with the `destroy` event should be saved I can see that the model doesn't validate. I get this message when I try to save the version model at that point:

`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Item can't be blank`

When I look at what validators belong to the version model I can see that `:item` is one attribute which is validated against:

```rb
[<ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x007fe90cb3be40 @attributes=[:event], @options={}>,
 <ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x007fe9044c82a0 @attributes=[:event], @options={}>,
 <ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x007fe9044cbce8 @attributes=[:item_type], @options={}>,
 <ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x007fe90e022f20 @attributes=[:item], @options={}>]
```

Is there something I'm missing here? My activerecord model is really simple:

```rb
class ClientNote < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Right. You have to understand that I'm still fairly new to the magic of rails.

Apparently there [is a gem](https://github.com/SchemaPlus/schema_validations) which automatically adds validators to rails models depending on the schema. That's what prevented the paper_trail gem to work for me.